# How to get textField data from TableView Cell and display it in collectionView?

Tags: swift

I am making a word application. And in this application, the user will write a word in the textField on the tableView I created and this word will create a cell in the CollectionView. Then that word will appear as a label on the cell. I achieved this. But when I want to add more than one word, the label on the same cell changes? What I want is for the next word I add to create a label on the other cell. How can I solve this?

CollectionView:

```
class HomePageCollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController {
    
    var homePageView : HomePageView!
    var wordsBrain = WordsBrain()
    let newdeckvc = NewDeckViewController()
    var values: [String] = []
    var words : [WordsBrain] = []
    // MARK - COMPOSITIONAL LAYOUT
    
    init() {
        super.init(collectionViewLayout: HomePageCollectionViewController.createLayout())
    }
    
    static func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
        return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { (sectionNumber, env) ->
            NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
            let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: .init(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1)))
            item.contentInsets.trailing = 15
            item.contentInsets.leading = 15
            item.contentInsets.bottom = 15
            let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: .init(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .absolute(150)), subitems: [item])
            let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
            return section
        }
    }
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return values.count
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "deckViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DeckCellCollectionViewCell
            cell.backgroundColor = .red
            cell.configure(with: values[indexPath.item])
            return cell
        case 1:
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
            cell.backgroundColor = .red
            return cell
        default :
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
            cell.backgroundColor = .red
            return cell
        }
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0 :
            let detailViewController = UIViewController()
            detailViewController.view.backgroundColor = .white
            detailViewController.title = " \(indexPath.row)"
            navigationController?.pushViewController(detailViewController, animated: true)
        default:
            let detailViewController = UIViewController()
            detailViewController.view.backgroundColor = .white
            detailViewController.title = " \(indexPath.row)"
            navigationController?.pushViewController(detailViewController, animated: true)
        }
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupUI()
        collectionView.register(DeckCellCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "deckViewCell")
    }
    
    private let cellId = "cellId"
    
    private func setupUI() {
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        homePageView = HomePageView(frame: self.view.frame)
        self.view.addSubview(homePageView)
        title = "SMARTCARDS"
        addTargetButton()
        homePageView.anchor(top: nil, paddingTop: 0, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, paddingBottom: 0, left: nil, paddingLeft: 0, right: nil, paddingRight: 0, width: 370, height: 80, centerXAnchor: view.centerXAnchor, centerYAnchor: nil)
    }

    private func addTargetButton() {
        homePageView.newCardButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(newCardButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        homePageView.importButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(importButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        homePageView.infoButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(infoButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    @objc func newCardButtonTapped() {
        let vc = NewDeckViewController()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
    
    @objc func importButtonTapped() {
        let vc = ImportViewController()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        
    }
    
    @objc func infoButtonTapped() {
        print("infoButtonTapped tapped")
    }
}
```

TableViewController:

```
protocol ImagePickerDelegate : AnyObject {
    func didTapButton(_ button : UIButton)
    func didSelectButtonInCell(_ cell : DeckImageTableViewCell)
}
// MARK - CREATE PROTOCOL FOR TEXTFIELD
protocol TextFieldDelegate {
    func sendValue( _ value: [String])
}

class NewDeckViewController : UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate   {
    
    private var tableView = UITableView()
    private var newDeckView = NewDeckView()
    let newDeckCell = NewDeckTableViewCell()
    let deckText = ""
    var values : [String] = []
    var selectedImage: UIImage?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureTableView()
    }
    
    private func configureTableView() {
        self.view.addSubview(newDeckView)
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        setTableViewDelegate()
        tableView.register(NewDeckTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "deckCell")
        tableView.register(DeckColorTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "colorCell")
        tableView.register(DeckImageTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "deckImage")
        configureNavigationbar()
        newDeckView.pin(to: view)
        configureView()
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        title = "New Deck"
        values = Array(repeating: "", count: 3)
    }
    
    private func imagePicker(sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.sourceType = sourceType
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        return imagePicker
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            selectedImage = image
            if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 3, section: 0)) as? DeckImageTableViewCell {
                cell.updateImage(image)
            } 
        }
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    public func showImagePickerOptions() {
        let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "Pick a Photo", message: "Choose a picture from Library or camera", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        
        let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default) { [weak self] (action) in //Capture self to avoid retain cycles
            guard let self = self else {return}
            let cameraImagePicker = self.imagePicker (sourceType: .camera)
            cameraImagePicker.delegate = self
            self.present(cameraImagePicker, animated: true) {
                //TODO
            }
        }
        
        let libraryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Library", style: .default) { [weak self] (action) in //Capture self to avoid retain cycles
            guard let self = self else {return}
            let libraryImagePicker = self.imagePicker (sourceType: .photoLibrary)
            libraryImagePicker.delegate = self
            self.present(libraryImagePicker, animated: true) {
            }
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction (title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertVC.addAction(cameraAction)
        alertVC.addAction(libraryAction)
        alertVC.addAction(cancelAction)
        self.present(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @objc func doneButtonTapped() {
        guard let cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "deckCell") as? NewDeckTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("Wrong cell file")
        }
        sendValue(values)
    }
    
    @objc func cancelButtonTapped() {
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    
    private func configureView() {
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        tableView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        tableView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemGray.cgColor
        tableView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2.0, height: 2.0)
        tableView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        tableView.layer.shadowRadius = 2
        tableView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        tableView.clipsToBounds = true
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 100),
            tableView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor , constant: 20),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor , constant: -140),
        ])
    }
    
    private func configureNavigationbar() {
        navigationItem.backButtonTitle = "Cancel"
        navigationItem.title = "New Deck"
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(doneButtonTapped))
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelButtonTapped))
    }
    
    private func setTableViewDelegate() {
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension NewDeckViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource , TextFieldDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    func sendValue(_ value: [String]) {
        let homePageVC = HomePageCollectionViewController()
        homePageVC.values = value
        navigationController?.pushViewController(homePageVC, animated: true)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            guard let cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "deckCell") as? NewDeckTableViewCell else {
                fatalError("Wrong cell file")
                
            }
            cell.configure(with: values[indexPath.row], tag: indexPath.row, delegate: self)
            
            return cell
        case 1:
            guard let cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "deckCell") as? NewDeckTableViewCell else {
                fatalError("Wrong cell identifier")
            }
            return cell
        case 2:
            guard let cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "colorCell") as? DeckColorTableViewCell else {
                fatalError("Wrong cell identifier")
                
            }
            return cell
        case 3:
            guard let cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "deckImage") as? DeckImageTableViewCell else {
                fatalError("Wrong cell identifier")
            }
            cell.delegate = self
            return cell
        default :
            guard let cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "colorCell") as? DeckColorTableViewCell else {
                fatalError("Wrong cell identifier")
            }
            return cell
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0 :
            return 60
        case 1:
            return 60
        case 2:
            return 120
        case 3:
            return 200
        default:
            return 60
        }
        
    }
    
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        
        let text = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
        let tag = textField.tag
        values[tag] = text
        return true
    }
}

extension NewDeckViewController : ImagePickerDelegate {
    
    func didSelectButtonInCell(_ cell: DeckImageTableViewCell) {
        showImagePickerOptions()
    }
    
    func didTapButton(_ button: UIButton) {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "deckImage") as? DeckImageTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("wrong identifier")
        }
        cell.delegate?.didTapButton(button)
    }
```

}

TableViewCell :

```
class NewDeckTableViewCell: UITableViewCell,UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    let deckLabel = UIComponentsHelper.createCustomLabel(text: "Deck Name", size: 15, labelBackGroundColor: .clear, textColor: UIColor.systemGray, fontName: "Poppins-SemiBold")
    let deckNameTextField = UIComponentsHelper.createTextField(placeholder: "Enter Deck Name...")
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        configureViewCell()
        deckNameTextField.delegate = self
    }
    
    private func configureViewCell(){
        setSubviews()
        setupUI()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let updateText = (textField.text as NSString?)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) ?? ""
        print("Güncellenen metin: \(updateText)")
        return true
    }
    
    func configure(with text: String, tag: Int, delegate: UITextFieldDelegate) {
        deckNameTextField.text = text
        deckNameTextField.tag = tag
        deckNameTextField.delegate = delegate
    }
    
    private func setupUI() {
        deckLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        deckLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
        deckLabel.anchor(top: topAnchor, paddingTop: 10, bottom: nil, paddingBottom: 0, left: leftAnchor, paddingLeft: 10, right: nil, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0, centerXAnchor: nil, centerYAnchor: nil)
        deckNameTextField.anchor(top: deckLabel.bottomAnchor, paddingTop: 10, bottom: bottomAnchor, paddingBottom: 5, left: leftAnchor, paddingLeft: 10, right: nil, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0, centerXAnchor: nil, centerYAnchor: nil)
        
    }
    
    private func setSubviews() {
        contentView.addSubview(deckLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(deckNameTextField)
    }
}
```

Comment: You should include your code as text

Comment: I edited the code

Answer (score -1):

```
import UIKit

class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

var textFieldData: [String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    // Set up your data source for the collection view
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell
    cell.textField.delegate = self
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
    cell.label.text = textFieldData[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

}

```
extension MyViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: textField.superview as! UITableViewCell) {
        let updatedText = (textField.text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
        textFieldData[indexPath.row] = updatedText
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
    return true
}
```

}

Comment: 1. Please format your answer correctly. 2. Please do not post code-only answers. A good answer explains what was wrong and it explains how the answer solves the problem.